# Is Tomboy of Sterling Comics, from 1954, the first independent superheroine in comics?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero

Is Tomboy of Sterling Comics, from 1954, [the first](https://pdsh.fandom.com/wiki/Tomboy#Notes) independent superheroine in comics?

"Superheroine" because she's a 10-year-old girl that [can](https://archive.org/details/CaptainFlash001/page/n21/mode/2up) cling to the outside of a plane and jump into the water.

Unless that's actually possible, in which case the question becomes "Who's the real first?"

Comment: Is "independent" intended to modify comicbook or superheroine?

Comment: The Pippi Longstocking *novels* go back to 1945, but you specified *comic books*, and the first Pippi comic books (in Swedish) started in 1957.

Comment: @SamAzon - Superheroine. How to phrase...

Comment: What does "independent" mean in this context? Financially independent, like Batman? Not a member of a political party?

Comment: Mary Marvel, from 1942?

Comment: Wonder Woman is from 1941 and should fit any definition of "independent".

Comment: Tomboy is considered the first KID heroine who isn't a sidekick. https://pdsh.fandom.com/wiki/Tomboy

Answer (score 8):

**There are a considerable number of ***solo*** female superheroes that pre-date 1954.**

One of the earliest in comics is [*Fantomah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantomah), previewing in [Jungle Comics #2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantomah) (Feb, 1940) and then appearing in [Jungle Comics #3](https://www.comics.org/issue/689/) (**March, 1940**) in her own self-titled strip. Fantomah had a range of powers including the ability to command animals, sense what's happening in the jungle, change her appearance and cause fear.

[image]

---

We also have [*The Woman in Red*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woman_in_Red_(comics)), a masked crimefighter that debuted in [Thrilling Comics #2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrilling_Comics) in **March, 1940**. She has no specific superpowers, but she does operate as a vigilante in much the same mould as Batman.

[image]

---

A solid contender is also [*Miss Fury*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miss_Fury), who first appeared in **April, 1941** in a strip titled *The Black Fury*. Donning a magical catsuit, she gains super-strength and agility.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Definitely not first independent superheroine, but possibly first independent KID superheroine**

If "independent heroine" means one who isn't a sidekick or derived female character (like Mary Marvel), then Wonder Woman (first appearance October 1941) well predates Tomboy.

However, according to [this fandom wiki](https://pdsh.fandom.com/wiki/Tomboy), "Tomboy is possibly the first female kid superhero (or to specify even more, heroine) who wasn't someone's sidekick."

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I didn't realize it, but I was looking for kid superheroines. Even so, for the question I stated, I have found [Olga Mesmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olga_Mesmer) of 1937.

She [has / had](https://archive.org/details/spicy-mystery-stories-november-1937/page/54/mode/2up) "phenomenal strength which [Olga's guardian] has been in mortal dread for years" along with her titular 'x-ray eyes'.

[image]

Comment: A very good find. I'm not sure that she quite meets the criteria for being fully independent, but she's certainly super-powered.